# asp.net in Windows server reusing session of last login

Tags: asp.net, session, c#-4.0, iis-7

I'm using Windows 2012 server and my app asp.net framework 4.0 use SQL sever session mode. 
If 1 user login everything is OK, but if user 2 login in same time the user(1) found session information of user (2)!

The session save information about last login only!

How do I create a different session for every user?

Comment: Are you using a cookie to store session, and are you expiring your cookie?

Comment: Yes, use cookies but without expire, but the problem I'm login from different PC, and I found session 1 info in another PC 

Comment: Here's a post about Asp sessions that I hope will be helpful: http://forums.asp.net/post/7504.aspx